# Is it considered a bad thing to choose a book character's name as yours in Chinese? Picking a name from a book etc?

Tags: names

So, I am in a process of finding a good name for myself in Chinese.
I wanted it to be somehow connected to space, maybe astrophysics, maths etc. The thing that actually inspired me to sign up for a Chinese course was 三体 book, and I was just wondering if taking a name from it would be considered stupid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK from 三体, since names from it are generally 'normal', however in many literature works the names are very unusual and awkward if they were used in real world, since they are carefully picked to make the possibility that there are people with the same names in the real world. (since which may cause problem) I haven't read much western literature but I guess things are probably the same.

Answer (score 1):

> *I was just wondering if taking a name from it would be considered stupid?*

Depend on how common the name is. Names like 國強 or 家明 are like John or David in English. Even the main character in a famous novel is named John, no one would think it is stupid to name yourself John. Only you know this name was inspired by that John in that famous novel.

If we know which character you are talking about just by the name, it is probably not a good idea. For example, a name that appeared only in one particular book.

Family name matter too. No Chinese whose last name is 周 would name his child 周恩來 (蔡恩來 would be ok). ; No English speaker would name a child Harry Potter, but Harry with any other last name would be fine because Harry is such a common name

Comment: Agree. Having the exactly same name as some very famous people or characters does sound weird.

Comment: Weird? Well,it depends on who the famous people are or were. Not sure if there were any Adolf Hitler(s) around, but "According to the Social Security Administration’s baby name data, 19 new Baracks were born in 2016. This represented an increase from previous years: In 2015, eight boys were named after the former president, and both in 2014 and 2013, 11 kids got his name" And in Islam, Prophet Mohammad is the epitome of a perfect person, so "Mohammad" becomes the default name for 1600 years & counting. But "Donald" is too common to be associated with "him" But is there a Mao Tse-tung around?

Answer (score 0):

Although 《三体》 is a famous sci-fi series, not everyone have read it, and many people actually don't remember names of people except some main characters or those with distinct characteristics (e.g. some that I remember: 叶文洁，罗辑，章北海，丁仪).

So in your case, my suggestion is that it will be fine to choose a name from the book, as long as it is not of famous characters. Most likely other people will not find where you take that name from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right it is not good.

please do not find a name which is known to others.

a very simple way to find a name is the name you can speak loudly.

consider you are in a big class room and a teacher call your name.

he can loudly speak your name.

Comment: Quote:- "consider you are in a big class room and a teacher call your name" This reminds me of an incident that happened to my sister some years ago. She has a name that sounds like a famous Hong Kong actress. She was at a medical clinic in HK and when the nurse called her name the whole room turned to catch a look, and it was pretty disconcerting when they all turned away with disappointment on their faces.

Comment: what is your sister's name

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't put her name here without her permission. But the actress name is 裕玲, and here she is in the middle -- https://youtu.be/b2KZ7ywaXOU

Comment: I am sorry I do not know 裕玲